# How do you make blockchain applications using node?

Tags: node.js, express, blockchain, bitcoin

I've worked with blockchain and bitcoin processing in the past, but it was PHP, everything there seems pretty straightforward. You generate a new address, user sends bitcoin to the address, blockchains' scripts calls your callback php file.

But what if my application does not use PHP and it's made in Node.JS? How do you check if a user sent money to the address generated? What if the application is offline?

Thanks.

Comment: The protocol is the same, it's just your client... did you try any npm package yet? Your question appears to be off-topic as it does not concern a reproducible programing problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have not developed any bitcoin related nodejs applications, yet. But since your question is about blockchain applications and generating addresses and transactions, you can use the [ethereumjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereum) and [web3js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3) modules offered to interact with ethereum nodes.

```
$ npm install web3
```

Check if it's available in your app:

```
window.console.log(web3);
```

And connect it, for example:

```
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
```

Check out the full API documentation on creating accounts and [transactions](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction).